# Create a dataframe of missing data from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dataframe, tree

I am extremely new to Python (< 1 week), and I hope to read in three "variables," `PMID`, `Abstract Text`, and `Mesh` into a dataframe. My .xml is 10 GB.

Right now the following code produces a list of the PMIDs and the Abstract Texts. How would I convert it into a dataframe where there are 3 variables, `PMID`, `Abstract Text`, and `Mesh`, in which each `DescriptorName` within the `Mesh` from the XML is separated by a comma (for ex: Adenocarcinoma, Antineoplastic Agents, Colorectal Neoplasms)? Please note that the following snippet is only 1 `PMID`. There are about 1.8 mil in total.

Please note that some PMIDs do not contain any Abstract Texts or Mesh...in that case, I would like `NA` or "" to stand in place for its row.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

# read in all PMIDs and Abstract Texts - got too scared to parse in Mesh incorrectly since it's very time consuming to re-run
pmid_abstract = []
for event, element in etree.iterparse("pubmed_result.xml"):
    if element.tag in ["PMID", "AbstractText"]:
        pmid_abstract.append(element.text)
    element.clear()
```

This contains only the relevant tags in .xml for one PMID only

```
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">29310420</PMID>       
        <Article PubModel="Print">
            <Abstract>
                <AbstractText Label="RATIONALE" NlmCategory="BACKGROUND">Regorafenib is the new standard third-line therapy in metastatic colorectal cancer (mCRC). However, the reported 1-year overall survival rate does not exceed 25%.</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="PATIENT CONCERNS" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">A 55-year-old man affected by mCRC, treated with regorafenib combined with stereotactic body radiotherapy (SBRT), showing a durable response.</AbstractText>
            </Abstract>
        </Article>
        <MeshHeadingList>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName UI="D000230" MajorTopicYN="N">Adenocarcinoma</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName UI="Q000000981" MajorTopicYN="N">diagnostic imaging</QualifierName>
                <QualifierName UI="Q000628" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapy</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName UI="D000970" MajorTopicYN="N">Antineoplastic Agents</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapeutic use</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName UI="D015179" MajorTopicYN="N">Colorectal Neoplasms</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName UI="Q000000981" MajorTopicYN="N">diagnostic imaging</QualifierName>
                <QualifierName UI="Q000628" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapy</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
        </MeshHeadingList>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want.

I appended a copy of the complete `PubmedArticle` element that you posted to the end of the xml file and then enclosed the two elements in a single `PubmedArticles` (plural) element, to demonstrate the principle involved in processing such files. Because your file is so large I chose to put temporary results into a sql database table, and then to import them from there into pandas.

The first time through the loop there is no record to process. Afterwards, each time a `PMID` element is encountered this implies that the previous `PubmedArticle` has been completely processed and is available for storing to the database. As other elements are encountered they are simply inserted into the dictionary representing the current article.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('ragtime.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ragtime')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ragtime (PMID text, AbstractText Text, DescriptorName Text)''')

with open('ragtime.csv', 'w') as ragtime:
    record = None
    for ev, el in ElementTree.iterparse('ragtime.xml'):
        if el.tag=='PMID':
            if record:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO ragtime VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [record['PMID'], ' '.join(record['AbstractText']), ','.join(record['DescriptorName'])])
            record = {'PMID': el.text, 'AbstractText': [], 'DescriptorName': []}
        elif el.tag=='AbstractText':
            record['AbstractText'].append(el.text)
        elif el.tag=='DescriptorName':
            record['DescriptorName'].append(el.text)
        else:
            pass
    c.execute('INSERT INTO ragtime VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [record['PMID'], ' '.join(record['AbstractText']), ','.join(record['DescriptorName'])])

conn.commit()

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ragtime', conn)
print (df.head())

conn.close()
```

It produces the following printed result.

```
       PMID                                       AbstractText  \
0  29310420  Regorafenib is the new standard third-line the...   
1  29310425  Regorafenib is the new standard third-line the...   

                                      DescriptorName  
0  Adenocarcinoma,Antineoplastic Agents,Colorecta...  
1  Adenocarcinoma,Antineoplastic Agents,Colorecta...
```